# ld: library not found for -lJTCalendar on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I installed JTCalendar using cocoa pods into my project but when I run the project on the XCode Simulators, it shows an error

> ld: library not found for -lJTCalendar
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It is working fine when I debug the project using a real time device. WHy am I facing this issue on the simulator?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for your replies. Actually the issue was that when I installed the pods, the pod project architecture was set to arm64 armv7 armv7s and Build active architectures only was set to YES. My real time device was armv7 and the simulator was x86_64. I changed Build active architectures only to NO in the pod project and the issue was fixed. Thanks again.